# How do a define a global variable in the ember-cli environment?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm in the process of porting my ember app to ember-cli. I have top level function I'm using that's define like `var fooBar = function(a) { };`.

I moved that to app/utils/foo-bar.js (it was all in js/app.js), and added `export default fooBar;` to the end of the file.

I think that would be fine if the place I was using it could do an import, but for reasons I don't want to get into, I need defined as a global variable.

But I still want it in app/utils/ and to be able to import it, as I might rewrite the thing causing me to need it to be a global someday.

Is there some way to maybe have a `<script>` tag in my index.html that looks up the module and assigns it to a global variable?

Edit:

My `forBar` function that I want to be global needs to reference another variable via an import statement. But in `/vendor` I can't use `define` or `import`.

So just throwing it in `/vendor` just gives me back the same problem but for a different variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fooBar = require(['path/to/foo-bar']).default;
</script>
```

What I didn't realize is ember-cli is using requirejs, once I figured that out, I realized this is actually a requirejs question.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky workaround is to put it in a file in the `/vendor` folder and then `app.import` that file. That will add it to the `vendor.js` file making the global available in the browser context.

Comment: That doesn't work because the function does an import of its own, but import and define become syntax errors in `/vendor`. I'll add that info to my question.